# Sometimes Geofence not getting triggered

Tags: android, google-maps, android-geofence

I have created a Geofence in my driver app to inform the user has arrived at the pickup location. Geofence gets triggered once driver entered in the pickup area. I have set the 200-meter radius for the Geofence. But Sometimes it is not getting triggered on driver app.

```
 mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);
 mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
.setRequestId(entry.getKey())

.setCircularRegion(
        entry.getValue().latitude,
        entry.getValue().longitude,
        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS )
.setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
.setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
.build());
```

What will be the possibilities for Geofence not getting triggered?